# embed Angular Elements app within AngularJS app throws error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, element

I have an angular JS app I am trying to embed an Angular 12 element into as step 1 of an upgrade process. The Angular element consists of a few different components that help for the screen I am injecting, and I am able to build, bundle and load the new web component fine on its own. However, when I inject it into the angular app (app-bundle.js which consists, of all 4 scripts files) it partially loads the UI and then prints this error to the log:

[image]

I am defining my elements as customElements inside of ngDoBootstrap in the Angular12 app, but it almost seems like the AngularJS app is loading the components too quickly or something. Any help?

Comment: A minimal reproduction on StackBlitz is needed.

Comment: I can easily spin up an angular12 app, but making a reproduction of the angularJS isn't easily reproducible. This seems to be a common situation I'd imagine people face, and could potentially point to a solution.

Comment: The lack of answers seems to suggest otherwise. Without code to debug, the community can't help you.